# android MVVM What's the right way to setViewModel to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-architecture

I am practicing Google MVVM https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-databinding, having a problem of linking Fragment and ViewModel.

The google demo doing like this:

in Activity,

1. `Fragment.newInstance()`
2. `new ViewModel()`
3. `fragment.setViewModel(viewModel). (Implementing a setViewModel method in Fragment)`
4. `viewmodel.loadingData() in fragment's onResume or onStart`

My question is, this seems not safe. If due to some reason, system recycle fragment and recreate using default constructor, `viewModel` will be null ?

am I right or am I missing something?

As a workaround, I think put the new `ViewModel()` in Fragment's `onCreateView` method should be fine?

Answer (score 1):

You should not create new instance of the ViewModel anywhere in `Fragment` or `Activity`. The correct way is to obtain the instance by using the `ViewModelProviders` and a `ViewModelProvider.Factory`

There are many article around the net about `MVVM` and `ViewModel` using `dagger2` such as [this](https://medium.com/@marco_cattaneo/android-viewmodel-and-factoryprovider-good-way-to-manage-it-with-dagger-2-d9e20a07084c) or [this](https://medium.com/@dpreussler/add-the-new-viewmodel-to-your-mvvm-36bfea86b159)

Comment: I'm not using any Google architecture component yet, so no AndroidViewModel. Not using Dagger2 either.  If so, where should be my viewmodel created safely?